How can I avoid interface repetition in Python function signatures and docstrings?
I'm looking for a standard, lightweight (preferably built-in) way to handle the problem of interface repetition—where the same parameters (with annotations, defaults, and docs) are repeated across multiple functions that share common functionality. Is there a way to centralize the parameter definitions and docs without manually duplicating them?
Here's an example to illustrate the issue. The code is kept short and simple to avoid verbosity, and yes, in this particular case, a decorator could handle it. However, please focus on the repetition of signature elements and documentation as the real problem, not the specific logic of the functions.
Example Code:
# Core function f
def f(a: str, b=1) -> str:
    """
    Repeats the string `a` `b` times.
    
    Args:
        a (str): The string to be repeated.
        b (int, optional): Number of repetitions. Defaults to 1.
    ...
    """
    return a * b

# Higher-level function g
def g(x, *, a: str, b=1) -> str:
    """
    Calls `f` to repeat `a`, appends `x` to the result.
    
    Args:
        x: Value to append to the repeated string.
        a (str): The string to be repeated.
        b (int, optional): Number of repetitions. Defaults to 1.
    
    ...
    """
    result = f(a, b)
    return result + str(x)

# Higher-level function h (different from g)
def h(y, *, a: str, b=2) -> int:
    """
    Calls `f` to repeat `a`, appends `y`, and returns the length of the result.
    
    Args:
        y: Value to append to the repeated string.
        a (str): The string to be repeated.
        b (int, optional): Number of repetitions. Defaults to 2.
    
    ...
    """
    result = f(a, b) + str(y)
    return len(result)

The Problem
In this scenario, I find myself repeating parameter definitions (a, b) and their types and defaults across multiple functions. Similarly, the documentation for each parameter is repeated in each function's docstring. This leads to:

Visual noise: Repetition clutters the code, making it harder to maintain.
DRY violation: If I need to change the default of b or update the docs, I must do it in multiple places.
Harder maintenance: Changes in one place can lead to inconsistencies if I forget to update all the functions.

Mitigation Approaches
Some solutions I've considered (e.g. i2.signatures, which we developed with my previous team, to address this issue, and more) include:

Using decorators to centralize parameter handling. For example, a decorator could handle default values and inject common parameters across functions.
Using inspect to dynamically copy the signature from one function to another, reducing duplication.

However, these approaches still add complexity and don’t seem like an ideal solution for every case. They also don't fully address the problem of duplicating docs.
What I'm Looking For
Is there a standard or lightweight solution (preferably built-in) that addresses this interface repetition problem in Python? Ideally, it would avoid repetition of both parameter signatures and docstrings, while keeping the code as simple and readable as possible.
Any suggestions or best practices are welcome!

"it would avoid repetition of both parameter signatures and docstrings, while keeping the code as simple and readable as possible" - The most readable function definition is the one which docstring directly contains all necessary information. This conflicts with the idea to remove duplicated descriptions from the docstrings of similar functions. That is, I don't think that your problem has an approach which is the best for all cases. Just decide what your want to write in your code when define your functions, and create a decorator which will add remaining ("duplicating") information.

This may not be the answer you're looking for, but when I encounter situations like this, I just use cross-links to avoid repetition.  For example:
def h(y, *, a: str, b: int = 2) -> int:
    """
    Calls `f` to repeat `a`, appends `y`, and returns the length of the result.
    
    Args:
        y: Value to append to the repeated string.
        a: See :func:`f`.
        b: See :func:`f`.
    
    ...
    """

Some comments:

Cross-links also make it easier for users to find related functions, which is a mild benefit all on its own.
I don't like the idea of having any documentation that's automatically written. Argument descriptions are admittedly a relatively benign example of that, but when I'm reading docs that I can tell were not written by hand, I lose faith that they're actually correct.
In this exact situation, the argument descriptions are so short and simple that I think the costs of being DRY outweigh the benefits.  So I'd just write them twice.
There's no need to include the argument types, or whether or not each argument is optional, in the docstring. All of this information is readily available in the signature itself.

